# How to add JSON data from API url into database (MongoDB)?

Tags: database, mongodb

I am not able to add JSON data into MongoDB database. 
API link: http://starlord.hackerearth.com/kickstarter

I am getting error as `Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32` how can I fix the error as I want to insert JSON data in to mongo database and then query it.

Comment: post the code which is producing this error

Comment: I have used this site for checking is it valid JSON or not https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @ArpitSolanki https://imgur.com/a/v8ukB

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I have messaged you on Facebook please help me in resolving doubt.